# powered by joomla

Tags: joomla

is it necessary to have this at the bottom of my joomla site ? If i remove it will it violate any terms ?

Comment: here is a link of how to do it.... I cannot advise on the legal side of it. Consult the EULA [http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=309845](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=309845)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla is licensed under GPL version 2 or later. You are free to remove the link from the template, or create your own template that does not have the link. While you are required to leave the copyright and license notices in the code, you are not obligated to leave the link to joomla.org on your public facing website.